# Format Chart.JS Data Element To Be Currency

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, chart.js

I found that you can format the x or y axis of Chart.JS to currency by a quick JavaScript callback function

```
callback: function(value, index, values) {
    if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
        return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    } else {
        return '$' + value;
    }
}
}
```

but this does not seem to be the case for the `data:`  In my instance this is a JavaScript 1D Array that holds numeric values, and I want to add a dollar sign, and comma where applicable.  How can this be added with Charts.jS

**EDIT**
This is how I am populating my JSON array - and I want to format the data in the `data: values`

```
var barChartData = {
    labels: labelsarr,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Amount',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: values
    }]

};
```

And the JSON array is in this format `["AAAA",100,10000,2310,24420,30,50000,400000,70000,700,823200,923200,1111]`

I want to format starting at `index[1]` to show $ and currency.  How can this be achieved?

**2nd Edit Time**
I try to add title and format both data points and left axis as currency with below syntax, but this no longer displays anything on my page.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: labelsarr,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Test',
            data: values,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.8)',
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
                            return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                        } else {
                            return '$' + value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: '<?php echo $name ?> Test'
        }
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(t, d) {
                    var xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
                    var yLabel = t.yLabel >= 1000 ?
                        '$' + t.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") :
                        '$' + t.yLabel;
                    return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with this? It works perfectly.

Comment: @ℊααnd - I edit my post -> to further illustrate how the JSON array is set.

Comment: @ℊααnd - that formats the left axis as currency which I already have done with the 1st function I have posted.  I am wanting to format the data point as currency so when you hover over the bar graph when it shows the amount it is Currency format.  For example, if you hover over one of the Letters, I want it to show the amount formatted in currency.  It currently just shows a straight number string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be achieved using the following tool-tips label callback function ...

```
tooltips: {
   callbacks: {
      label: function(t, d) {
         var xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
         var yLabel = t.yLabel >= 1000 ? '$' + t.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") : '$' + t.yLabel;
         return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
      }
   }
}
```

---

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ**

```js
var labelsarr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M'];
var values = ["AAAA", 100, 10000, 2310, 24420, 30, 50000, 400000, 70000, 700, 823200, 923200, 1111];

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: labelsarr,
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Amount',
         data: values,
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.8)',
      }]
   },
   options: {
      tooltips: {
         callbacks: {
            label: function(t, d) {
               var xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
               var yLabel = t.yLabel >= 1000 ? '$' + t.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") : '$' + t.yLabel;
               return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
            }
         }
      },
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               callback: function(value, index, values) {
                  if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
                     return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                  } else {
                     return '$' + value;
                  }
               }
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: That removes the formatting I have on the left side.  I want the left side as well as the data points to have currency formatting.

Comment: Then keep your prev function for y-axis ticks.. This is for tooltips not y-axis ticks

Comment: See my edit.  I attempt to modify syntax, but now I have nothing display on my page.

Comment: you missed comma `,` after closing `title` property `},`